# missing some results from mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have such a interesting situation.
Here is table named "mirror_data"  =>

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_mir     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| local      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| local_mir  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remote     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remote_mir | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and here is second table named "data"

---

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       | 
| localParty      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| other columns ...                                             |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm retrieving information from data table, but i want that, when (from "data" table) column localParty equal to (table from "mirror_data") column local, then retrieve information from local_mir column (also from "mirror_data" table), otherwise when marked columns are not equal each other, retrieve information from localParty. But I want to retrieve whole information from "data" table.

here is mirror_data inserted values =>

```
+--------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+
| id_mir | local  | local_mir | remote | remote_mir |
+--------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+
|      1 | 715715 | Something | NULL   | NULL       |
|      2 | 1000   | some      | NULL   | NULL       |
+--------+--------+-----------+--------+------------+
```

and here is my code how I'm "doing" this =>

```
select IF(o.localParty=m.local,m.local_mir,o.localParty) FROM data as o, mirror_data as m limit 0,10;
```

and also here is result what this query does (missing some values) =>

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| IF(o.localParty=m.local,m.local_mir,o.localParty) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Something                                         |
| 715715                                            |
| 14                                                |
| 14                                                |
| Something                                         |
| 715715                                            |
| Something                                         |
| 715715                                            |
| 978080                                            |
| 943080                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Like you seen number 715715 is not changed in this case because in mirror_data table are two values (and when their will be more , it will be more possibility not to receive expected result) , how can I write query to achive my goal ?

Just want to retrieve whole information from "data" table, but with changing (localparty) if marked situation happens (local=localparty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html#LEFT), in order to include all info from `data` table and info from `mirror_table` when available..

If there is no match then `m.local_mir` will be `NULL` so you can use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

***edited to answer sub-question in comment***

```
SELECT
   IFNULL(m.local_mir, o.localParty) as local,
   IFNULL(m.remote_mir, o.remoteParty) as remote
FROM 
   data as o
   LEFT JOIN mirror_data as m 
      ON (o.localParty = m.local OR o.remoteParty = m.remote)
LIMIT 
   0,10;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, please answer one question too , how this query will be if we add remote, exactly same column and table , just rename local to remote , please answer :)

Comment: I have one question too, this script works fine when from localparty and from remoteparty (separately) equal to (accordingly) local and remote, but when they match together within one row , that row duplicate. (I am guessing that it is happening because of "OR" statement,but I can not done it with AND and OR) Sorry for disturbing , but please help again :)

Comment: If it isn't possible to accomplish above marked problem, I will separate table for local and remote ( I mean in one table named "loc_mir" I will have (local and local_mir columns) and in second table named "rem_mir" (remote and remote_mir columns). And in this situation how will be query to retrieve information just for localParty (the same will be for remoteParty). In this situation I think LEFT JOIN will not be goo variant. So if above marked solution isn't possible than please just give query which change localParty to local but not with LEFT JOIN, because I have to do same with remoteParty

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively joining tables `data` and `mirror_data`, but have no joining condition in a `WHERE` clause to define how the two tables are related.

```
SELECT
  IF(o.localParty = m.local, m.local_mir, o.localParty) 
FROM
  data as o,
  mirror_data as m
/* Need an equivalent column to join on */
WHERE o.some_column = m.some_related_column
limit 0,10;
```

Using the newer, preferred `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT
  IF(o.localParty = m.local, m.local_mir, o.localParty) 
FROM
  data AS o,
  JOIN mirror_data AS m ON o.some_column = m.some_related_column
LIMIT 0, 10;
```